# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, attributeerror

I am trying to turn a variable into a pandas `DataFrame`.  The following is my code:

`pk = pd.DataFrame()`

This is what I am wanting to use the DataFrame for:
`pk['product_id'], pk['UOM'] = [ss_uom.product_id, ss_uom.UOM]`

This is the error I am experiencing directly after declaring `pk` as a DataFrame:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-2dd2e5d04c54> in <module>()
----> 1 pK = pd.DataFrame()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5139             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5140                 return self[name]
-> 5141             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5142 
   5143     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

I'm not sure what the problem is specifically with this variable as I have declared about half a dozen similar variables as DataFrames directly above this variable in a Google Colab notebook, **with the exact same process and all have passed successfully.**

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: somewhere (or some time if you use Jupyter notebook), you have `pd = pd.DataFrame()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that pd itself is not a DataFrame?
you can check it with the type function:

```
type(pd)
```

It must return 'module'. Otherwise, you should check your code for the wrong assigning of pd variable.